# Public network must provide notification for sign-in after connection

Tags: wifi, android, captive-portal

I noticed that some public networks require sign-in after connection, aka **Captive Portal**.

I am implementing my own Captive Portal, and my clients (mostly mobile devices) need to know that my public network requires sign-in after connection.

I would something like Android's behavior:

[image: Sign into network]

**What is the direction to achieve this behavior?**

Comment: If you actually deploy a captive portal properly, this will happen _automatically_.

Comment: I guess some kind of "setting" must be defined, right?

Comment: No, there is no "setting". Please let me know what was confusing about my last statement.

Comment: I am planning to make my clients be redirected via DNS to the login page. Is it enough?

Comment: Buy a router that have a guess service on it ?

Comment: That would not be a proper captive portal, and wouldn't work anyway. Do yourself a favor, and use an existing captive portal software (e.g. PacketFence).

Comment: @Richard: You've been given the general direction in which to proceed, why don't you go do some research, reading and learning for yourself.

Comment: Right! Thank you! I decided to use build my own but using existing tools: http://blog.trifork.com/2013/01/15/building-a-captive-portal-controlling-access-to-the-internet-from-your-network/

Answer (score 2):

This might happen automatically with a proper captive portal. However be aware that the sign in 'recognition' that you see on that android device is not a feature of the wireless network itself, but a feature of the client device. In other words it is up to client devices whether or not they are able to detect if an open wifi network has a captive portal running.